# Python - How to create more than one object in a single class?

Tags: python, regex, function, class, object

I am trying to instantiate more then one object in a single class. I am trying to instantiate them in the class instead of the main function. I am new to python, so trying to learn. Example, I have this piece of code, my input file is a text file with all strings. I want to instantiate the object when my regex in region is true and/or sub-region is true. I want to instantiate them there and NOT in the main function. How can I do that? since every time I run my code I can have zero or one or two objects:

```
class Tracker(object):

  def __init__(self):
      self.region = ""
      self.subregion = ""

  def updateRegion(self,input):
      if self.endingRegion:
          self.region = ""
      if self.endingSubRegion:
         self.subregion = ""

      #Regions
      temp = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'(.*)\'', input)
      if temp:
          self.region = temp.group(1)
          print self.region

      #SubRegions  
      temp = re.search(r'Equipped Type \(if different\)',input)
      if temp:
         self.subregion = "Equipped Type"
         print self.subregion


def main():
  with open ('/home/thamer/TS_ncren202_XRS-20_20150624_12.0.R6.txt','r') as f:
    tracker = Tracker()
    for line in f: 
      tracker.updateRegion(line)
      region = tracker.getRegion()
      subregion = tracker.getSubRegion()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: You cannot create an instance of a class in the class definition itself.

Why do you not want to check your regex in the main function? Even regardless of the language, I think it makes more sense from a design point of view.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You want to create instances of what? Where?

Comment: I guess you should have a look to what is called class methods

Comment: Your `Tracker` class has two methods, one of which is `__init__`. [So it is basically a function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). (Have a look at the video I linked to; you might find it useful.)